# OPENJSON TSQL SQL query Nested Json

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql, nested

Here is my json

```
declare @response NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'
[
  {
    "request": "MSFT",
    "type": "Symbol",
    "results": [
      {
        "type": "Company",
        "id": "0C000008EC",
        "tables": {
          "corporate_calendars": [
            {
              "company_id": "0C000008EC",
              "begin_date_time": "2013-01-24",
              "end_date_time": "2013-01-24",
              "event_type": 8,
              "estimated_date_for_next_event": "1970-01-01",
              "event": "Microsoft Fiscal Year 2013 Second Quarter Earnings",
              "event_fiscal_year": 2013,
              "event_status": "Confirmed",
              "time_zone": "1970-01-01"
            },
            {
              "company_id": "0C000008EC",
              "begin_date_time": "2015-01-26",
              "end_date_time": "2015-01-26",
              "event_type": 13,
              "estimated_date_for_next_event": "1970-01-01",
              "event": "Microsoft Corp Second quarter earnings Conference Call in 2015",
              "event_fiscal_year": 2015,
              "event_status": "Confirmed",
              "time_zone": "1969-12-31"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

I'm looking for data like this to inset into a table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02PGu.png)

```
request type    results_type    results_id  company_id  begin_date_time end_date_time   event_type  estimated_date_for_next_event   event   event_fiscal_year   event_status    time_zone
MSFT    Symbol  Company 0C000008EC  0C000008EC  1/24/2013   1/24/2013   8   1/1/1970    Microsoft Fiscal Year 2013 Second Quarter Earnings  2013    Confirmed   1/1/1970
MSFT    Symbol  Company 0C000008EC  0C000008EC  1/26/2015   1/26/2015   13  1/1/1970    Microsoft Corp Second quarter earnings Conference Call in 2015  2015    Confirmed   12/31/1969
```

this is as far as i got :

```
select * from openjson(@response)
with(
    [request] nvarchar(100)'$.request',
    [type] nvarchar(100)'$.type'
) x
```

which gives me the first 2 columns only :

I'm just not good at this :( -- any help is greatly appreciated. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve a whole JSON object or array in the `OPENJSON WITH` schema, by using `nvarchar(max) AS JSON`.

Then you can `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON` feeding that JSON into the next call, and so on.

Do note that this will give you a giant join of all those JSON objects. And you don't need to pass a path explicitly unless it differs from the default.

```sql
SELECT
  j1.request,
  j1.type,
  j2.results_type,
  j2.results_id,
  j3.company_id,
  j3.begin_date_time,
  j3.end_date_time,
  j3.event_type,
  j3.estimated_date_for_next_event,
  j3.event,
  j3.event_fiscal_year,
  j3.event_status,
  j3.time_zone
FROM OPENJSON(@response)
  WITH (
    request nvarchar(100),
    type nvarchar(100),
    results nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.results)
  WITH (
    results_type nvarchar(100) '$.type',
    results_id nvarchar(100) '$.id',
    calendars nvarchar(max) '$.tables.corporate_calendars' AS JSON
  ) j2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.calendars)
  WITH (
    company_id nvarchar(100),
    begin_date_time date,
    end_date_time date,
    event_type int,
    estimated_date_for_next_event date,
    event nvarchar(1000),
    event_fiscal_year int,
    event_status nvarchar(100),
    time_zone date
  ) j3;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/IJLAPauO)

Comment: that is sweet - i will look into cross apply - its complicated to understand since i am not a developer but looks very powerful. TY so much i truly appreciate it.

Comment: So i started working with Cross Appy and its super powerful. TY for that. Here is another one : https://dbfiddle.uk/6JqXYebh I cant seem to get to  the ownership summary node ? 'ownership_summary' i.e.

Comment: Needs to be `nvarchar(max) AS JSON` and the path needs to start `$.`. You might want to use `OUTER` instead of `CROSS`, but note that you are currently getting a giant cartesian join between all the tables https://dbfiddle.uk/EU_na848